# Best way to update nested arrays in C# / MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

This code is failing:

```
    public async Task InsertFile(string projectId, string folderId, File file)
    {
        var project = await Find(projectId);
        var folderIndex = project.Folders.IndexOf(project.Folders.Single(x => x.Id == folderId));
        var update = Builders<Project>.Update.Push(x => x.Folders[folderIndex].Files, file);
        await Collection().UpdateOneAsync(x => x.Id == projectId, update);
    }
```

The error given is:

```
Unable to determine the serialization information for x => x.Folders.get_Item(value(Launch.Business.Database.ProjectStore+<>c__DisplayClass3_0).folderIndex).Files.
```

So I cannot target nested arrays by index.

I need atomic updates to work. I can't save the whole project, as folder updates are extremely rapid and may collide / override each other.

Given this constraint, what is the shortest and sweetest way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that the above code will work, but it doesn't work with the expression syntax.

Replacing the expression syntax with a string fixes it:

```
var update = Builders<Project>.Update.Push($"Folders.{folderIndex}.Files", file);
```